# In R dplyr, why there is a single quote after spread function?

Tags: r, dplyr, spread

I am trying to spread a column into multiple columns using dplyr spread function. Once spread, the access to the column has a single quote which I want to remove since it comes in the way of my filtering the dataframe

Following is my code

```
# Create Test Frame
testframe = data.frame(name = c("foo-tt.0","bar-tt.0","dd-tt.0","tt-tt.0"),age=as.numeric(c(40,38,10,8)))
#Pivot using name
testframe_pivot <- testframe %>% spread(name,age)
```

I need to access the frame like below

```
testframe_pivot$`bar-tt.0` ## I don't want these quotes
[1] 38
```

Why I cannot get like (EXPECTED OUTPUT)

```
> testframe_pivot$bar-tt.0
[1] 38
```

instead I get

```
> testframe_pivot$bar-tt.0
Error: object 'tt.0' not found
```

I understand they are because of the mix of alphabets and other characters but not sure how to get rid of this error

Consequence is..

```
>name_I_want = c("foo-tt.0")

>select_(testframe_pivot,.dot=name_I_want)
Error in .f(.x[[i]], ...) : object 'foo' not found
```

Comment: `dplyr::select(testframe_pivot, name_I_want)` seems to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with the names is the `-` sign. Unless you get rid of it, you won't be able to use the `$` operator without back ticks. There are two options with base-R:

Either you correct the names to something syntactically correct for R. `make.names` works well:

```
names(testframe_pivot) <- make.names(names(testframe_pivot))
testframe_pivot
#  bar.tt.0 dd.tt.0 foo.tt.0 tt.tt.0
#1       38      10       40       8
```

Or you subset with `[[` and strings:

```
testframe_pivot[['bar-tt.0']]
#[1] 38
```